# I set featured images on my post but has_post_thumbnail is still false

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a home page that will pull in different posts to display them in a custom format. I can get most of the information I want but I haven't been able to to get the featured image for any of them. I set a featured image for all three posts and I'm using my own theme that's a child of the twentysixteen theme. I get has_post_thumbnail returning false on all of them even though I've uploaded a featured image for each post. I only have this on local right now but here's the code I'm using to get the posts:

```
<?php
        global $post;
        $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=3&category=1');
        foreach($myposts as $post) : 
            setup_postdata( $post );?>
            <div class="article-box">
                <div class="article-box-image">
                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) { ?>
                        has one
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        not working
                    <?php } ?>
                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="article-box-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </div>
                <div class="article-box-excerpt">
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="article-box-edit">
                    <?php edit_post_link('Edit'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: did you try printing out the post id? $id should also contain the post id. But the loop (google it) is normally the best way to do these things even for a small number of posts.

Comment: You like this? <?php $post->ID; ?> That doesn't give me anything. It's outside of the loop because I'm trying to add this on the homepage.

Comment: echo $post->ID someone has kindly provided the loop below. For the code above if $post->ID is empty you wont get a thumbnail from the function. Something odd is going on here double check your postmeta fields for each post to make sure there is a thumbnail id and then try removing all other plugins/check if you have custom code to filter the thumbnail

Comment: How do I check the for the thumbnail id? I see the images in the Featured Image section on the Edit Post pages.

Comment: check the db but the images are there, so if you pass the post id (hard code the id) into get the thimbnail , you should see a thumbnail if yes, your post id is not being passed correctly, if no there is a filter changing the code

Comment: While I was doing something else, I removed the "preview" url variables and now it works. Do you know why preview mode would do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a wp query:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'cat'                    => '1',
    'posts_per_page'         => '3',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="article-box">
            <div class="article-box-image">

            <?php //check for thumbnail
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                     the_post_thumbnail();
                }
                else {
                    //Give up and start new life picking apples
                } ?> 

            </div>    
            <div class="article-box-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="article-box-excerpt">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="article-box-edit">
                <?php edit_post_link('Edit'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

And then double check that thumbnails are supported in your theme's functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

Comment: Didn't work, I got all the other information but still no thumbnails. It's supposed to create the thumbnail sizes automatically right? I haven't changed the default settings.

Comment: yep, it'll create thumbnails alright, unless something else is going on with your theme. Check the wp-content/uploads folder to be sure.

Comment: What is the html output of the above?

Comment: No output for the thumbnail and I do see the different image sizes in the uploads folder.

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized that the "preview" post parameters were the problem. I was viewing the page through preview page. I don't know why images won't work in preview mode but apparently it won't.